# When libc6 will be updated for Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, packages

I have problem with getting latest version of libc6 on my Ubuntu 18.04 and some other packages in general.

As it can be seen on [this](https://pkgs.org/download/libc6) page, there is libc6 2.32 for latest Ubuntu, but the highest version of libc6 available for my OS is 2.27.

Am I getting something wrong? Should LTS versions be supported or not? If I want fresh packages in apt do I need to update to 20.04 or will they appear for 18.04 at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Released versions of Ubuntu will never upgrade upstream package versions, only backport security fixes and extremely important bug fixes.

Therefore your best options are:

- Use some kind of container or virtualisation technology to run a 20.04 release on your 18.04 release;
- Upgrade to 20.04;
- Rebuild the software you want to run, so it works on your current 18.04 machine.